# Adding the token as query at the end of URL with Nginx

Tags: node.js, angularjs, nginx, jwt

I have a webpage that I am working on its password reset service.
So normally when I check other websites I see that they redirect you to a new page if you have forgot your password and they add a token at the end of the URL like:

```
www.domain.com/security?token={token}
```

I know how this works at the backend (Node.js and JWT to create a token).
But my problem is with frontend since when I add `?token={token}` at the end pf my URL, its redirecting that to homepage. I dont how I will be able to do it.

Comment: that all depends how login works in your app - where user login - on page served by your server or on page served by external server or ...

Comment: this has no any relation with login.

Comment: Too many unknowns here for anyone to do much more than guess. Certainly sounds like a server side routing issue